# Shortest way to achieve target angle

Tags: geometry

Suppose I am moving in a certain compass bearing (e.g. $270^\circ$) and I want to be going in a different direction (e.g. $120^\circ$). Is there a formula or series of math operations that I can use to determine which direction I should turn (I want the shorter direction)?

I've tried to increase my angle, i.e. turn counterclockwise, if $\text{target bearing} - \text{current bearing} < 360 - (\text{target bearing} - \text{current bearing})$, and it only seems to work in some cases.

Please help! I've been having lots of trouble.

Comment: I've edited this as I understand it. If I interpreted your question incorrectly, please change it or let me know.

Comment: That's correct, thanks. As you might guess, English isn't my mother tongue. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $T$ be the target bearing and $C$ be the current bearing.  Let's consider three numbers:

$$\begin{align}\alpha&=T-C\\
\beta&=T-C+360°\\
\gamma&=T-C-360°\end{align}$$

Now, whichever of $|\alpha|$, $|\beta|$, and $|\gamma|$ is the smallest tells us which of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ is relevant and if the one with the smallest absolute value is positive, go clockwise, and if it's negative, go counterclockwise.

*edit* The animation below shows the locations of the target point in red and the current point in blue, for various values of each, with the values of $|\alpha|$, $|\beta|$, and $|\gamma|$ as well as the motion (which is indicated by an arc along the circle) shown in the lower right corner.

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely best answer one can ever get! Thanks for amazing visualizing too, I am more of visual learner. :) Couldn't thank you enough!

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for a "one-liner", let $T$ be the target bearing and $C$ be the current bearing:

$$\begin{align}\delta&=(T-C+540°)\bmod360°-180°\end{align}$$

The shortest rotation distance in degrees is given by $\delta$. Positive values indicate clockwise rotation, negative values indicate counterclockwise rotation.

$180°$ turns are always expressed as counterclockwise $-180°$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Say you're going at bearing $a$ and your target bearing is $b$. I'll assume that both $a$ and $b$ are between zero (inclusive) and 360 (exclusive), and I'll also assume that the direction of increasing bearing is counterclockwise (that's the usual convention in higher math, and I think it's the one you are using). Here are the cases:

If $a\lt b$, and $b-a\le180$, turn counterclockwise.

If $a\lt b$, and $b-a\gt180$, turn clockwise.

If $a\gt b$, and $a-b\le180$, turn clockwise.

If $a\gt b$, and $a-b\gt180$, turn counterclockwise.